# $f$-factors and fractional $f$-factors and odd cycles

Tags: graph-theory

For a graph $G=(V,E)$ and a nonnegative integer valued function $f$ defined on $V$, an $f$-factor of $G$ is a spanning subgraph $F\subseteq G$ such that $d_F(v)=f(v)$ for all $v\in V$. A fractional $f$-factor is a function $h:E\to [0,1]$ such that for any vertex $v\in V$, $\sum_{\{e|e=uv\}}h(e)=f(v)$.

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph such that every pair of vertex disjoint odd cycles in $G$ are connected by an edge and let $f:V\to \mathbb{N}_0$ be a function such that $\sum_{v\in V}f(v)\equiv0\mod 2$. Prove that $G$ has an $f$-factor if and only if $G$ has a fractional $f$-factor.

I have almost nothing. I've started in the one direction: suppose that $G$ has a fractional $f$ factor $h$. Then for any vertex $v$, $\sum_{\{e|e=uv\}}h(e)\leq d_G(v)$, so there are at least enough edges.

But that's all I have and I am so stumped. I have no idea how to utilize the assumption that vertex disjoint odd cycles are connected.

Can anyone help with this?

---

**Edit**

As a commenter pointed out, the one direction is simple. Given an $f$-factor $F$ we can simply form a fractional $f$-factor $$h(uv)=\begin{cases} 1 & uv\in E(F) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

But the other direction is still a mystery.

Comment: One direction seems easy.  If you have a $f$-factor $F$, then you can construct $h$ such that $h(uv) = 1$ if $uv$ is an edge of $F$, and 0 otherwise.  The other direction does not seem easy at all.  What I can tell you is that the vertex-disjoint odd cycles connected by an edge is necessary.  Otherwise, you can construct a counter-example like this : let $G$ be two vertex-disjoint triangles, and let $f(v) = 1$ for all $v$.  Then you can have $h(uv) = 1/2$ for all edges.  But $G$ has no $f$-factor, even though it has a fractional $f$-factor.  Adding an edge between the triangle corrects this.